# I want to make three Map in using below JSON response using model classes. Please share

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I am a started to learn flutter, i am a beginner, i am stucking one point,I have API response related to checkBox.I want to map the values in to different map.

Here is the API response:

```
{
    "sms": {
        "very_low": true,
        "low": true,
        "medium": true,
        "high": false,
        "very_high": true
    },
    "email": {
        "very_low": true,
        "low": true,
        "medium": true,
        "high": true,
        "very_high": true
    },
    "mobile": {
        "very_low": true,
        "low": true,
        "medium": true,
        "high": true,
        "very_high": true
    }
}
```

This is the actual model class,

```
class NotifigrationSetup {
  Sms? sms;
  Sms? email;
  Sms? mobile;

  NotifigrationSetup({this.sms, this.email, this.mobile});

  NotifigrationSetup.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sms = json['sms'] != null ? new Sms.fromJson(json['sms']) : null;
    email = json['email'] != null ? new Sms.fromJson(json['email']) : null;
    mobile = json['mobile'] != null ? new Sms.fromJson(json['mobile']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.sms != null) {
      data['sms'] = this.sms!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.email != null) {
      data['email'] = this.email!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.mobile != null) {
      data['mobile'] = this.mobile!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Sms {
  bool? veryLow;
  bool? low;
  bool? medium;
  bool? high;
  bool? veryHigh;

  Sms({this.veryLow, this.low, this.medium, this.high, this.veryHigh});

  Sms.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    veryLow = json['very_low'];
    low = json['low'];
    medium = json['medium'];
    high = json['high'];
    veryHigh = json['very_high'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['very_low'] = this.veryLow;
    data['low'] = this.low;
    data['medium'] = this.medium;
    data['high'] = this.high;
    data['very_high'] = this.veryHigh;
    return data;
  }
}
```

So i want make three Map items like, sms,email,mobile, using this model. I am stucking in this section ,kindly request share your ideas

Comment: Please edit the question. What you exactly want is unclear!

Comment: Thank you for response,I want to make three seperate Map , from above API response using this model.